# What are the factors affecting a page to be printed

Tags: c#, jquery, printing

In my application I am printing a HTML web form . Its giving different layouts in different systems eventhough printer and its settings are same . The only difference is monitor and browser versions. So what are the factors needed to be changed .

Comment: Completely impossible to answer your question without more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to provide print only styles with CSS.
1. Media query for printer http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp
2. Rules where to and where not to break the page http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp
You have to play around with adjusting styles for printer inside media query (point 1) and page breaks (point 2).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate stylesheet to format your page specifically for printing. Check out this link for more info:

http://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint/